# How signals work

Tags: linux, unix, signals

I have been studing signals for along time now, but i want to understand how they really work, i need some indepth answer to this question please

If a process send a signal to another process using the libc function for example.

1-can this process send the signal normally without going into the kernel space or does it have to go into the kernel space when it wants to send a signal?

2-and if it have to go first to the kernel, what are the steps that are taken to do that ?

3-where are these signal handlers ? do they exist in the user-space or the kernel-space and what about the default signal handler?

4-When a process recieves a signal? does it have to go through the kernel in order to execute the signal handler?

Comment: if an app's signal handler were "in-kernel", then there'd essentially be ZERO security on any unix system, since every app would able to inject code into kernel space just by making it a signal handler. the actual signal sending mechanics are in-kernel, but the actual handler remains where it should - userspace.

Comment: I know that most signal handlers exist in the userspace, but is there any exception to that ?

Comment: No idea if there's any signal usage inside the kernel. Probably is, but I'm not sure how it'd be necessary, since signals are more for inter-process stuff, rather than intra-process.

Comment: I think the timer interupt signal would be in the Kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1 Sending a signal is eventually done by a system call. All system calls are executed by the kernel.
- 2 Not sure how deep you want to go. The first step is for the kernel to make sure you are allowed to send the signal, the last one is for the kernel to either process itself or deliver the signal to the target process.
- 3 Most signal handlers are in user space, except for SIGSTOP and SIGKILL which are taken into account by the kernel.
- 4 No, there is no such requirement. The process either ignore or process the signal. The handler is either a default or a custom one.

Comment: ok how signal and sigaction system calls work if they do not write the signal handler to the kernel

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "write the signal handler to the kernel". The signal handler stays in userland, it is userland code, not kernel one. Both `signal` and `sigaction` are updating a table which is part of the process context. A signal sent to a process is also stored in this process context. When the scheduler is about to give back the CPU to a process, it checks if a signal need to be delivered. In such case, a custom handler might be executed by the target process.